# How to decode a JWT token in Go?

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I am currently working on a Go application. I receive a JWT token from the client side and I need to decode that token and obtain the relevant information: user, name, etc.

I was checking the libraries that are available to handle JWT tokens and I came down to [`dgrijalva/jwt-go`](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go), but I don't see how to accomplish my goal in a simple way.

I have the token and I need to decode the info into a map or at least a json. How can I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/master/example_test.go

Comment: @zerkms I already saw it, but in that example I should have the struct with of the data that I will going to receive, in this case MyCustomClaims, but that can easily change from the other side and I don't want to be reestructuring that anytime that something is added or deleted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go Language and Verify JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077953/go-language-and-verify-jwt)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Function [`jwt.ParseWithClaims`](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#ParseWithClaims) accept an interface of `jwt.Claims` as the second argument. Besides struct-based custom claims, the package also provides `map`-based claims, i.e. [`jwt.MapClaims`](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#MapClaims). 
So, you can simply decode the token into a `MapClaims`, e.g.

```
tokenString := "<YOUR TOKEN STRING>"    
claims := jwt.MapClaims{}
token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte("<YOUR VERIFICATION KEY>"), nil
})
// ... error handling

// do something with decoded claims
for key, val := range claims {
    fmt.Printf("Key: %v, value: %v\n", key, val)
}
```

Comment: Be aware that if you are using custom claim based on `jwt.StandardClaims` (or standard claims directly), you should pass reference of the claims (`jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &claims, ...)`. Maybe it saves someone else's  couple minutes :)

Comment: You can pass `nil` as third param `KeyFunc` if you don't need to verify token.

Comment: Please note that `dgrijalva/jwt-go` has been unmaintained for a long time. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68159566/4108803) for further details

Answer (score 24):

**Disclaimer: I am not affiliated to the library. I'm just a user, find it useful and would like to share.**

It's 2019. I would like to suggest an [alternate library](https://github.com/square/go-jose/) that does pretty good job on JWT using JWS and/or JWE.

Here is the few examples on how to use the library:

```golang
import (
    "gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2/jwt"
    "gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2"
)
...

var claims map[string]interface{} // generic map to store parsed token

// decode JWT token without verifying the signature
token, _ := jwt.ParseSigned(tokenString)
_ = token.UnsafeClaimsWithoutVerification(&claims)

// decode JWT token and verify signature using JSON Web Keyset
token, _ := jwt.ParseSigned(tokenString)
jwks := &jose.JSONWebKeySet { // normally you can obtain this from an endpoint exposed by authorization server
            Keys: []jose.JSONWebKey { // just an example
                {
                    Key: publicKey, 
                    Algorithm: jose.RS256, // should be the same as in the JWT token header
                    KeyID: "kid", // should be the same as in the JWT token header
                },
            },
        }
_ = jwt.Claims(jwks, &claims)
```

Noted that, `claims` can be a struct that contains default JWT fields and also customized fields that are inside the token
E.g.:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
    "gopkg.in/square/go-jose.v2/jwt"
)
...
type CustomClaims struct {
    *jwt.Claims
    // additional claims apart from standard claims
    extra map[string]interface{}
}

func (cc *CustomClaims) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var rawClaims map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &rawClaims); err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    var claims jwt.Claims
    var decoderResult mapstructure.Metadata
    decoder, err := mapstructure.NewDecoder(&mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
        Result:   &claims,
        Metadata: &decoderResult,
        TagName:  "json",
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := decoder.Decode(rawClaims); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cc.Claims = &claims
    cc.extra = make(map[string]interface{})
    for _, k := range decoderResult.Unused {
        cc.extra[k] = rawClaims[k]
    }
    return nil
}
```

I also built [a command line tool](https://github.com/trung/jwt-tools/) that uses the [library](https://github.com/square/go-jose/) to perform various encoding/decoding activities. It might be a useful reference on the usage of the library too.

Answer (score 21):

Since both the question and answers mention the JWT library `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`, please note that this library **has been unmaintained for a long time now.**

As of June 2021 there is a community fork [golang-jwt/jwt](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt), officially [blessed](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/462) by Dave Grijalva, the original author.

This also means that the library import path has changed. Note that the <strike>current</strike> major version `v3` is not on Go modules, therefore you will still see `v3.x.x+incompatible` in your `go.mod`.

---

**Edit:** since August 2021 version `v4` of `golang-jwt/jwt` is available. **This finally supports Go modules**. The new version is **backward-compatible** with previous versions, so in order to migrate simply replace the old import path with:

```
github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4
```

then update your modules as needed — see also the [migration guide](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/blob/main/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md) for details.

---

The fork most notably fixes [an important security issue](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/issues/6) with the original library. Before the fix, the library didn't properly handle multiple `aud` in the JWT claims, making it actually not compliant with the JWT spec.

Apart from that, the main API is still the same. For example to parse a JWT with HMAC verification:

```
    tokenString := /* raw JWT string*/

    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, errors.New("unexpected signing method")
        }
        return []byte(/* your JWT secret*/), nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
    }

    // validate the essential claims
    if !token.Valid {
        // handle invalid tokebn
    }
```

To parse a JWT with custom claims, you can define your own struct type and embed `jwt.StandardClaims` into it:

```
    type MyClaims struct {
        jwt.StandardClaims
        MyField string `json:"my_field"`
    }

    tokenString := /* raw JWT string*/

    // pass your custom claims to the parser function
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &MyClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, errors.New("unexpected signing method")
        }
        return []byte(/* your JWT secret*/), nil
    })

    // type-assert `Claims` into a variable of the appropriate type
    myClaims := token.Claims.(*MyClaims)
```

---

A valid alternative to this library is [`lestrrat-go/jwx`](https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx). The API is slightly different, but also very easy to use:

```
    tokenString := /* raw JWT string*/

    // parse and verify signature
    tok, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, jwt.WithVerify(jwa.HS256, []byte(/* your JWT secret */)))
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
    }

    // validate the essential claims
    if err := jwt.Validate(tok); err != nil {
        // handle err
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to get claims from jwt token **without validation**

```
import "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
...
    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenStr, nil)
    if token == nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    claims, _ := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    // claims are actually a map[string]interface{}
```

Note: code compares `token` with `nil`, not the `err`. The `err` will be `keyFunc can't be nil`.

Comment: doen't work in version 3.2.0, the error is `keyFunc can't be nil`

Comment: @You'reawesome that's the error, but the code doesn't compare `err` with `nil`, it compares the `token`.

Comment: Note that this library ("github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go") is discontinued; this fork is active: https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt

Answer (score 2):

Use `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` go liabary for the implementation. we can extract JWT token information from the api request according to the following way.

When post the JWT token from the using post request. you must extract JWT information in routing section.

```
  func RequireTokenAuthentication(inner http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            token, err := jwt.ParseFromRequest(
                r,
                func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
                    return VERIFICATION.PublicKey, nil
                })
            if err != nil || !token.Valid) {
                log.Debug("Authentication failed " + err.Error())
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
                return
            } else {
                r.Header.Set("username", token.Claims["username"].(string))
                r.Header.Set("userid", strconv.FormatFloat((token.Claims["userid"]).(float64), 'f', 0, 64))
            }
            inner.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
```

VERIFICATION.PublicKey :  The key for verification(get public key from public.key file in your system)

Any Issue happen.Please let me know. I can give you help.

Comment: And if I dont have any VERIFICATION.PublicKey?

Comment: You might be able to find the Public/VerifyingKey on your server at an endpoint ending with `.well-known/jwks.json`

Comment: This library is discontinued; this fork is active: https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt