# How to parse a set of JWK with x5c and verify JWT?

Tags: go, jwt, x509, jwk

I want to validate a JSON Web Token. The JSON Web Key for the verification are avaiable under [this url](https://shareduks.uks.attest.azure.net/certs). Those are JWKs with x509 certificates (x5c). Based on an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408538/13285647), tried the following:

```
import  "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
import  "github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk"

func verifyToken(tokenBytes []byte) {
    token, err := jwt.Parse(string(tokenBytes), getKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func getKey(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    set, err := jwk.Fetch(context.Background(), "https://shareduks.uks.attest.azure.net/certs")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    keyID, ok := token.Header["kid"].(string)
    if !ok {
        return nil, err
    }
    key, ok := set.LookupKeyID(keyID)
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("could not find key with kid")
    }
    return key, nil
}
```

But I get the following error

```
panic: failed to parse JWK set: failed to unmarshal JWK set: failed to unmarshal key #1 (total 5) from multi-key JWK set: failed to unmarshal JSON into key (*jwk.rsaPublicKey): required field e is missing
```

I could not find an example that uses x5c. A solution does not have to use the library I used in my example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that error (`required field e is missing`) is that the JWK Set from [this url](https://shareduks.uks.attest.azure.net/certs) is invalid. Even if a JWK contains `x5c` it still must contain the other [required public key members](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-6) for that specific `kty`, which for the RSA keys listed in that URL means having `n` and `e`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think you are right, this seems to be the problem. Is there a way to verify the token anyway? I means the information needed is in the x5c part. I thought of something like converting the content of x5c from DER to PEM and verify with the jwk package using PEM...

Comment: I don't have the details of your package but when `x5c[0]` gets base64url decoded it is the DER X.509 cert. When wrapped around with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n` + x5c[0] + `\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----` it is a valid PEM X.509 cert.

Answer (score 1):

Author of http://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx here.

I have not merged the ability to parse certificates yet pending response from the issue reporter, but the code is already written https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/compare/topic/issue-350

Once that change is in, it is possible to perform some arm twisting and parse those certificates (pseudocode):

```
data := ... read from that URL ...

rawSet := make(map[string]interface{})
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &rawSet); err != nil {
   ...
}

// yikes
keys := rawset["keys"].([]interface{})
firstKey := keys[0].(map[string]interface{})
x5c := (firstKey["x5c"].([]interface{}))[0].(string)

// Decode from base64 
cert, _ := base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString(x5c)

// turn the certificate into JWK (NOT YET MERGED)
key, _ := jwk.ParseKey(cert, jwk.WithPEM(true))
```

If you need the ability to parse certificates into JWKs, please file a new issue in the repository so I can track the change.

Also, if you are importing http://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk, you might as well use http://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwt for JWTs ;)