# How to iterate over the decoded claims of a Jwt token in Go?

Tags: go, jwt

I am referring to this post ([How to decode a JWT token in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405626/how-to-decode-a-jwt-token-in-go)) to get the claim fields of a Jwt token. Here are the code that I used based on this post:

```
tokenString := "<YOUR TOKEN STRING>"    
claims := jwt.MapClaims{}
token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte("<YOUR VERIFICATION KEY>"), nil
})
// ... error handling

// do something with decoded claims
for key, val := range claims {
    fmt.Printf("Key: %v, value: %v\n", key, val)
}
```

I managed to get those claims and its values. However, in this Jwt token, there is a claim field called 'scope', and it has a string array values, like '['openId','username','email'].

[image: claim values of Jwt token]

Now I want to iterate over these values using loop.

```
for _, v := range claims["scope"]{
      fmt.Println(v)
}
```

However, when I try to loop over this claims ["scope"], I got an error message saying that:

> "cannot range over claims["scope"] (type interface {})".

How to iterate over these claims["scope"] values? Also, is it possible to convert it to other forms, like string array or json, to iterate over it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can handle this; the simplest is probably to let the library decode things for you ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/TTleImvljof))

```golang
type MyCustomClaims struct {
    Scope []string `json:"scope"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

claims := MyCustomClaims{}
_, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte(sharedKey), nil
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for _, s := range claims.Scope {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
}
```

If you want to stick with the approach used in your question then you will need to use type assertions ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/HqrwbV5VUbc) - see the [json docs](https://go.dev/blog/json) for more info on this):

```golang
var claims jwt.MapClaims
_, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte(sharedKey), nil
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

scope := claims["scope"]
if scope == nil {
    panic("no scope")
}
scopeSlc, ok := scope.([]any)
if !ok {
    panic("scope not a slice")
}

for _, s := range scopeSlc {
    sStr, ok := s.(string)
    if !ok {
        panic("slice member not a string")
    }
    fmt.Println(sStr)
}
```