# How to generate pem from jwk in go

Tags: go, pem, jwk

I'm trying to generate a pem string using [`github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk`](https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx).

But so far I coudn't, I'm guessing it's because I'm new to go and there's something I'm not understanding.
I have gone through [the relevant examples of this library](https://godoc.org/github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk#pkg-examples).

My code fetchs a JWK from a server, once I have it, I try to generate a pem string here :

```
// validationCrt contains my []byte from the server
set, err := jwk.Parse(validationCrt)
if err != nil {
    println(err)
}

// I suspect this piece of code is actually a mess
// but I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong
key, err := jwk.GetPublicKey(set)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("failed to create public key: %s", err)
}
```

I am really lost I tried multiple ways (with and without this lib) and it seems I can't find any example out there (they usually explain how to generate a key, or go from pem to jwt, but my Go app is a client.)

Comment: From the docs it looks like [the Materialize method](https://godoc.org/github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk#Key) returns the corresponding type from the standard library. You should be able to find examples for how to marshal *those* into PEM using the [x509](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/) and [pem](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/) packages.

Comment: Thanks @Peter ! Thanks to your comment I found a question I didn't see before here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077953/go-language-and-verify-jwt
I had to refactor my code because I was trying to achieve this with another lib.

Answer (score 2):

Authorization server usually provides an endpoint to obtain JSON Web Keyset (JWKS). So I think `validationCrt` would indeed be a JSON Web Keyset. Nevertheless, you can `json.Unmarshal()` to JWK/JWKS ([square/go-jose](https://github.com/square/go-jose)) and obtain the reference of the public key via `.Key`.

Getting to PEM format is as simple as

```golang
...
pubData, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(pubKey)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
if err := pem.Encode(os.Stdout, &pem.Block{
    Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
    Bytes: pubData,
}); err != nil {
    return err
}
...
```