# Validate AWS Cognito JWT in GO

Tags: go, jwt

I am trying validate JWT returned from a login from AWS Cognito (hosted UI). I noticed that once the login is done in cognito, it tries to access my app with some params like "id_token" and "access_token". Checked with jwt.io and looks like "id_token" is the jwt.

As a test, I wrote a post function in GO expecting a body with the jwt token and the access token (and implemented from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947083))

```
func auth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    keyset, err := jwk.Fetch(context.Background(), "https://cognito-idp.{Region}.amazonaws.com/{poolID}/.well-known/jwks.json")
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&model.ErrorResponse{
            Response: model.Response{
                Result: false,
            },
            StatusCd:   "500",
            StatusDesc: "Failed to fetch jwks. Authorization failed.",
            Error:      "errRes",
        })
    }
    authRequest := &model.AuthRequest{}

    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&authRequest)

    parsedToken, err := jwt.Parse(
        []byte(authRequest.Token), //This is the JWT
        jwt.WithKeySet(keyset),
        jwt.WithValidate(true),
        jwt.WithIssuer("https://cognito-idp.{Region}.amazonaws.com/{poolID}"),
        jwt.WithAudience("{XX APP CLIENT ID XX}"),
        jwt.WithClaimValue("key", authRequest.Access), //This is the Access Token
    )
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&model.ErrorResponse{
            Response: model.Response{
                Result: false,
            },
            StatusCd:   "500",
            StatusDesc: "Failed token parse. Authorization failed.",
            Error:      "errRes",
        })
    }

    result := parsedToken
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```

Packages I am using are

```
"github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk"
"github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwt"
```

Obviously, it failed at the token parse. What am I doing wrong and also what should I do with the `parsedToken` ?

I am new to this so, I have no clue if this is the correct approach and would really like some guidance.

Comment: I dont get this line ```jwt.WithClaimValue("key", authRequest.Access)``` does authRequest.Access evaluate to "access" ?  With the jwt as a string you can just B64 decode to see what <key,value>  claims are there, if its not there then that is at least on place things will fail. You should be able to decode it here https://jwt.io/  I think that line   WithClaimValue  should be key = "token_use"  and then value is "id"  or "access"

Comment: @NigelSavage Thank you - I changed it to `jwt.WithClaimValue("token_use", "access")` but it still fails.

Comment: I would suggest to decode the jwt token and see the claims

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `github.com/golang-jwt/jwt` package (formally known as `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`,) then you'd probably benefit from [this example](https://github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc/blob/master/examples/aws_cognito/main.go):

You can check out more JWKs Go examples here: [github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc/tree/master/examples](https://github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc/tree/master/examples).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt"

    "github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc"
)

func main() {

    // Get the JWKs URL from your AWS region and userPoolId.
    //
    // See the AWS docs here:
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html
    regionID := ""   // TODO Get the region ID for your AWS Cognito instance.
    userPoolID := "" // TODO Get the user pool ID of your AWS Cognito instance.
    jwksURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com/%s/.well-known/jwks.json", regionID, userPoolID)

    // Create the keyfunc options. Use an error handler that logs. Refresh the JWKs when a JWT signed by an unknown KID
    // is found or at the specified interval. Rate limit these refreshes. Timeout the initial JWKs refresh request after
    // 10 seconds. This timeout is also used to create the initial context.Context for keyfunc.Get.
    refreshInterval := time.Hour
    refreshRateLimit := time.Minute * 5
    refreshTimeout := time.Second * 10
    refreshUnknownKID := true
    options := keyfunc.Options{
        RefreshErrorHandler: func(err error) {
            log.Printf("There was an error with the jwt.KeyFunc\nError:%s\n", err.Error())
        },
        RefreshInterval:   &refreshInterval,
        RefreshRateLimit:  &refreshRateLimit,
        RefreshTimeout:    &refreshTimeout,
        RefreshUnknownKID: &refreshUnknownKID,
    }

    // Create the JWKs from the resource at the given URL.
    jwks, err := keyfunc.Get(jwksURL, options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create JWKs from resource at the given URL.\nError:%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    // Get a JWT to parse.
    jwtB64 := "eyJraWQiOiJmNTVkOWE0ZSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJLZXNoYSIsImF1ZCI6IlRhc2h1YW4iLCJpc3MiOiJqd2tzLXNlcnZpY2UuYXBwc3BvdC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2MTkwMjUyMTEsImlhdCI6MTYxOTAyNTE3NywianRpIjoiMWY3MTgwNzAtZTBiOC00OGNmLTlmMDItMGE1M2ZiZWNhYWQwIn0.vetsI8W0c4Z-bs2YCVcPb9HsBm1BrMhxTBSQto1koG_lV-2nHwksz8vMuk7J7Q1sMa7WUkXxgthqu9RGVgtGO2xor6Ub0WBhZfIlFeaRGd6ZZKiapb-ASNK7EyRIeX20htRf9MzFGwpWjtrS5NIGvn1a7_x9WcXU9hlnkXaAWBTUJ2H73UbjDdVtlKFZGWM5VGANY4VG7gSMaJqCIKMxRPn2jnYbvPIYz81sjjbd-sc2-ePRjso7Rk6s382YdOm-lDUDl2APE-gqkLWdOJcj68fc6EBIociradX_ADytj-JYEI6v0-zI-8jSckYIGTUF5wjamcDfF5qyKpjsmdrZJA"

    // Parse the JWT.
    token, err := jwt.Parse(jwtB64, jwks.KeyFunc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse the JWT.\nError:%s\n", err.Error())
    }

    // Check if the token is valid.
    if !token.Valid {
        log.Fatalf("The token is not valid.")
    }

    log.Println("The token is valid.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using this anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start out by doing the minimal checks -- i.e., first try just parsing without validation, then add validations one by one:

1. jwt.Parse([]byte(token)) // probably fails because of JWS
2. jwt.Parse([]byte(token), jwt.WithKeySet(...)) // should be OK?
3. jwt.Parse(..., jwt.WithValidation(true), ...) // add conditions one by one

Please note that I have no idea what's in id_token, as I have never used Cognito If it's a raw JWT, you shouldn't need a key set, and (1) should work.

Comment: I ended up using this solution for now https://stackoverflow.com/a/66574942/1456913 but I will also try your suggestion. Also, if you are THE lestrrat, thank you for your contribution :)